# How to fix .bash_profile when Terminal won't work

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm

I was trying to customize my prompt in Terminal.  To do this, I tried to edit `.bash_profile` using vim, but ended up with a `.bash_profile.swp` file.  Following some posts I found online, I used the `:recover` command in vim, which created a new `.bash_profile` and then deleted the .swp file. However, now Terminal does not seem to work. When I open it, I get the below message:

> -bash: c: command not found
>
> -bash: end: command not found
>
> [Process completed]

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: This question is probably better suited for [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to restore .bash\_profile on a mac? None of my unix terminal are working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21067625/how-to-restore-bash-profile-on-a-mac-none-of-my-unix-terminal-are-working)

Answer (score 21):

Something in your `.bash_profile` isn't as it should be. You seem to have a `c` and an `end` in it that `bash` interprets as command. If you  post the contents of the file (without comment lines) either here or in a [pastebin](http://www.pylonsproject.org/tools/pastebins) we'll probably be able to tell you where exactly those are.

Pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> in the file open dialog of TextEdit (or a real editor) should display dot-files in the dialog.

Comment: Tricky part is, that's a hidden file and terminal is the easiest way to view that file

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware of that technique! I'll have to remember it.

Comment: I was able to fix it! You were right that I had weird commands in the file (probably due to my fumbling around in vim). The key was learning how to see hidden files in Finder, and therefore open up the file. Once I did that I was able to fixt it.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Came here and I didn't know about the TextEdit nifty trick! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. Nothing like accidentally clobbering your PATH and then shitting bricks when you realize terminal is life

Answer (score 2):

I used the TextMate option Show Hidden Files.

Answer (score -1):

1. Open up TextEdit.
2. Bring up the Open sheet.
3. Hit "/".
4. Type "~/.bash_profile" and then return.
5. Open the (now highlighted) .bash_profile file.