# Terminal Not responding To ANY Commands

Tags: command-line, terminal, flutter-web

I've been trying to set up webdev so I can build websites using flutter, but then flutter commands wouldn't run in terminal so I undid everything. I thought it was fixed, but now when I'm trying to use terminal none of the commands work except for pwd.
`$ clear -bash: clear: command not found $ ls -bash: ls: command not found $ flutter --version -bash: flutter: command not found` 
I tried re-opening the PATH using `touch ~/.bash_profile; open ~/.bash_profile` but is says `-bash: touch: command not found -bash: open: command not found` 
Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to restore .bash\_profile on a mac? None of my unix terminal are working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21067625/how-to-restore-bash-profile-on-a-mac-none-of-my-unix-terminal-are-working)

Answer (score 0):

Doing `PATH=$(/usr/bin/getconf PATH)` will get you back to a minimal operational state.

Then you should be able to edit your bash startup files to undo the damage.

Comment: Thank you!  This helped me fix it for one window.  How do I change it so my terminal works whenever I open it or open a new window?

Comment: Fix your bash startup files, then logout and login again.